# Json document search with ability to group them by a field and return only the documents with the Maximum value of some other field within each group

Tags: json, group-by, marklogic, reduce

I want to find the best way to perform a server-side query to find JSON documents by some initial query criteria, then grouping all these documents by some field in the document and then reducing each group to only contain a single document that contained the highest integer value of another field.

Currently, we are using the results from the `jsonPropertyValueQuery`, then doing the filtering Java side. This is not optimal as some of our queries can return hundreds of large documents and we would prefer to avoid the data transfer overhead.

Lets say we have the below JSON documents found from the query `cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("typeId", "CAR")`:

**Document 1**

```json
{
  "id": "aa1234",
  "typeId": "CAR",
  "version": 1
}
```

**Document 2**

```json
{
  "id": "aa1234",
  "typeId": "CAR",
  "version": 2
}
```

**Document 3**

```json
{
  "id": "cc1234",
  "typeId": "CAR",
  "version": 1
}
```

I want a way to filter/reduce these documents server side (not console side) that allow us to return only **Document 2** and **Document 3**, since out of all the documents with the id=*aa1234*, **Document 2** has the highest(max) *version*, and out of all documents with the id=*cc1234*, **Document 3** has the highest(max) *version*.

If there is a way to do this from the Java API directly that would be ideal, but after researching it is looking like we are going to have to send a JavaScript/XQuery block using ServerEvaluationCall.

I have looked into using the JSearch reduce function, but without the ability to group them by the id first, it will only return the single document that contains the highest(max) version. In the above example it only returns Document 2, which is not what we need. Therefore, as stated above we have resorted to just filtering the group of documents Java side.

Comment: Why would document3 be returned? Did you mean to have it's version=2? Based upon your description, and the current examples I would think you would only want document2, because it has the highest version (2) and the others have version=1.

Comment: @MadsHansen We are needing to return the highest version of a group of documents that share the same "id". As shown above, document 1 and 2 have the same "id" ="aa1234" therefore out of these two documents document 2 has the higher version.. For document 3 it contains a different "id" = "cc1234" in this case and out of all the documents that have this id of "cc1234" (only one in this case but could be many) document 3 has the highest version in that group. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: ah, right - sorry that make sense. Not sure why I didn't read it correctly before.

Comment: why store the numeric `version` as a String?

Comment: Sorry it is not of type string in our database. I will change it above.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the results of the search, and capture the doc that has the highest `version` for each `id` in an object and then return the values as an Array, or convert into a Sequence:

```
const maxVersionByID = { };
for (const doc of cts.search(cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("typeId", "CAR")) ) {
  const obj = doc.toObject();
  const previousVersion = maxVersionByID[obj.id] ? parseInt(maxVersionByID[obj.id].version) : -1
  if (previousVersion < parseInt(obj.version)) {
    maxVersionByID[obj.id] = obj;
  }
}
Sequence.from(Object.values(maxVersionByID))
```

Comment: The two answers you have provided would at least take the code off of our java application which might be the only choice we have.. I  was more so thinking for a way to do this as apart of the query directly to where cts.search() or something like DocumentsSearch return the correct documents directly.. In the end I am looking for the best performance as we have millions of documents, so if you think doing javascript filtering will be just as good as finding out a way to do it in the query directly that that is fine with me.

As a side note, I was taking a look at AccessPlan.prototype.groupBy

Comment: Optic groupBy may be the way to go, especially for larger scale

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will look more into Optic groupby.  If I cannot get it to do what I want, I will just filter it javascript server side like suggested below. I will update this thread once the best solution is determined for others to see.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using a JavaScript [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const searchResults = cts.search(cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("typeId", "CAR")).toArray();
const maxVersionByID = searchResults.reduce(
    (entryMap, e) => { 
      const obj = e.toObject();
      const previousVersion = entryMap.get(obj.id) ? entryMap.get(obj.id).version : -1
      if (previousVersion < parseInt(obj.version)) {
         entryMap.set(obj.id, e) 
      }
      return entryMap;
    },
    new Map()
);
Array.from(maxVersionByID.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it in your Java server side, you can use JSON library *Josson* to transform the JSON documents.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Assume it is an JSON array to hold all the objects.

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "[" +
    "    {" +
    "        \"id\": \"aa1234\"," +
    "        \"typeId\": \"CAR\"," +
    "        \"version\": 1" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "        \"id\": \"aa1234\"," +
    "        \"typeId\": \"CAR\"," +
    "        \"version\": 2" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "        \"id\": \"cc1234\"," +
    "        \"typeId\": \"CAR\"," +
    "        \"version\": 1" +
    "    }" +
    "]");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("group(id)@.elements.findByMax(version)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
[ {
  "id" : "aa1234",
  "typeId" : "CAR",
  "version" : 2
}, {
  "id" : "cc1234",
  "typeId" : "CAR",
  "version" : 1
} ]
```